# Problem with everloop_demo from MATRIX Creator

Tags: gpio, pi-3, matrix-creator

I am attempting to set up and use the MATRIX Creator hardware.  I have taken the following steps with a Raspberry Pi 3 and Matrix Creator attached (be gentle, I'm new to linux, RPI, hardware in general)

- Downloaded and installed 2016-05-27-raspbian-jessie-lite.img on blank 16GB SD
- Expand /root to see entire SD
- Subsequent steps

  ```
  $echo "deb http://packages.matrix.one/matrix-creator/ ./" | sudo tee --append /etc/apt/sources.list  (needed for matrix creator)
  $sudo apt-get upgrade
  $sudo apt-get update
  $sudo apt-get install matrix-creator-init cmake g++ git
  $sudo raspi-config
      advanced options -> enable SPI
  $cd /opt
  $sudo git clone https://github.com/matrix-io/matrix-creator-hal.git
  $cd matrix-creator-hal
  $sudo mkdir build
  $cd build
  $sudo cmake .. -DADM_FATAL_WARNINGS=ON
  $sudo make
  ```

Everything seems to build without error, but I don't see any LED activity when I run:

```
    $demos/everloop_demo
```

Answer (score 2):

The steps have been simplified. Please take a look at the [Wiki](https://github.com/matrix-io/matrix-creator-quickstart/wiki) again and let us know if things work for you. SPI is enabled by matrix-creator-init package so you don't have to do it by hand.

If it doesn't work, try doing it in a fresh image of raspbian.

Answer (score 2):

The usual recipe (first update, then upgrade)

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

for the matrix-creator-hal

```
git clone https://github.com/matrix-io/matrix-creator-hal.git
cd matrix-creator-hal
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
```

Run the demos

```
cd demos
./arc_demo
```

Comment: It was suggested by an anonymous user via edit (rejected for other reasons) that **you may need to reboot following the upgrade** for this to work.